# ListInstance with predefined data in Field tag of Element.xml gives an error

Tags: list, sharepoint-hosted-app, elements-xml

I am trying to add data in Field tag like

```
  <Data>
  <Rows>
    <Row>
      <Field Name='Title'>Configuration</Field>
      <Field Name='JSONData'> { "URL":"https://example.com&Isdlg=1")
                </Field>
        </Row>
  </Rows>
</Data>
```

But it is giving me error on **&Isdlg** that Isdlg is not defined. I think because of **&** sign Isdlg is considered as a veriable. So is there is solution to store such data. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try wrapping it in CDATA tags

```
<Data>
  <Rows>
    <Row>
      <Field Name='Title'>Configuration</Field>
      <Field Name='JSONData'><![CDATA[{ "URL":"https://example.com&Isdlg=1"}]]></Field>
    </Row>
  </Rows>
</Data>
```

or escaping the ampersand

```
<Data>
  <Rows>
    <Row>
      <Field Name='Title'>Configuration</Field>
      <Field Name='JSONData'> { "URL":"https://example.com&amp;Isdlg=1"}</Field>
    </Row>
  </Rows>
</Data>
```